# Minimum Switching Current in Boost regulator Datasheet

Tags: current, voltage-regulator

I am planning to use TI TLV61220 in one of my designs. My design will be in sleep most of the time & the current in sleep mode is 10-20 uA. In active mode, it wil take max 10mA.

The device is powered from a CR123A battery which operates @ 3V down to 2.3V. I am stepping this voltage up to 3.3V fixed. I am planning to use TLV61220 for this purpose.

The datasheet says "Minimum Switching current - 200mA". Can some one clarify what it means?

The datasheet is :-

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv61220.pdf

Comment: Please read the **10.3.1 Controller Circuit** section on page 10, and update your question if you still do not understand. Also this IC is not an LDO but a switching regulator with boost topology.

Comment: You need to find a circuit with pulse skipping, burst mode or similar to pull this off.

Comment: @Bence Kaulics :- Yes, I read that but could not completely understand. Can you share some reference Document to understand the concept?